# How to create relationship between Custom object and Contact Object using SOAP API C#

Tags: custom-object, lookup, relationships

I have created a custom object in Salesforce named `Call_c`.  There is already a standard object in Salesforce named `Contact`

There is a field named `call_number_c__c` in my `Call_c` and `MobilePhone` field in `Contact` object.

Using SOAP API in C#, when I am going to create a dynamic entry in `Call_c` object, at that time I want to query if my `call_number_c__c` matches with the `MobilePhone` of `Contact` object. 
If it matches, I want to create a relationship between `Call_c` and `Contact`. So when I see it in my `Call_c` object in SalesForce, it will show the name of contact associated with `MobilePhone` in `Contact` object. 
For this, I have created a lookup field `parent_id__c` in `Call_c` object with data-type `Lookup(Contact)` 
I can manually go in the Salesforce site and can associate the Contact with the entry in call, but how can I achieve the same using SOAP API. 
I really don't have any idea about how to implement this. 
This is similar to `set_relationship` method used in SugarCRM. 
Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

It would be very helpful to me if you can provide little code snippet and mechanism so I can move forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your C# code you just have to update the parent_id__c with the id of the contact you found a match for.

**UPDATE**

```
//code that will match and get the record from Contact object

//this will update the id of the relantionship
Call_c updatedCall = new Call__c();
updatedCall.Id = callId; //Point to an existing Call__c record to update
updatedCall.parent_id__c = matchedContact.Id;

SaveResult[] saveResults = binding.update(updatedCall);
```

See more examples at this  [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/), on how to update more records, writing them in a try and catch exception, etc.

Hope it helps

Comment: Can you  provide a little code-snippet or rough lines of code, so that I can indulge in it give a final touch??

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: You saved my day buddy! Thanks! I will keep posting if I get any trouble again.. ;-)

Comment: I need one more doubt to be cleared. I have `Leads` module in my SalesForce. As I have put the `parent_id__c` field as lookup on `Contact`. What should I do if I want to relate this `updatedCall` with `Lead` as well? Do I need to create separate lookup field in `Leads` module as well? As per my requirement, I want that these two relationships be established in a single operation. Is it possible? Please suggest your thought about this.

Comment: Yes, you need to create a separate lookup relationship . I see no problem in them being updated at the same time. You might want to change the name of the lookup so you know that this is for contact and the other for lead.